# How to play video via byte array in videoview

Tags: java, android, video, android-video-player

In my project i want to play video with byte array, i dont want to store that byte array into temprory file, Suppose i have 300 mb file in encrypt form , now what i am doing is to decrypt that file and store into new one , for this i have 600mb size  for playing one file, so now i think is it possible to play video via byte array without creating any temprory file, i have checked videoview and mediaplayer class there is no method to play such as. so please suggest me how to do this , or this is possible or not

Comment: Did you found any solution?